# Вывод случайного элемента массива, заполненного в цикле

Tags: php, массивы, циклы, foreach

столкнулся с небольшой проблемой.
Получаю список пользователей в беседе с помощью API VK. Ответ от сервера переношу в массив. Необходимо после заполнения массива выбрать случайного пользователя. Само заполнение массива происходит без проблем, но после попытки вызова его вне цикла происходит ошибка.

Код:

```
$i=0;
echo 'Список:<br>';
foreach($members->response->profiles as $member)
{
    $members_id = array($i=>$member->id);

    // Здесь я сразу вывожу на экран результат, 
    // дабы убедиться что массив действительно заполняется
    echo $i.') ID: '.$members_id[$i].'<br>';
    $i++;
}

echo '<br>';
echo 'Длина массива: '.count($members_id).'<br>';
echo 'Пользователь:'.$members_id[rand(0,count($members_id))];
```

Ответ:

```
Список:
0) 52462477
1) 57547537
2) 35763673
3) 724165473
<...>
Длина массива: 1
Пользователь:
```

Проблема в том, что в конечном итоге массив состоит лишь из одной строки, с последним пользователем, хотя внутри цикла все было в порядке.
Читал об объявлении переменной глобальной, но это не помогало, результат аналогичный:

```
$i=0;
echo 'Список:<br>';
$members_id = array();
foreach($members->response->profiles as $member)
{
    global $members_id;
    $members_id = array($i=>$member->id);
    echo $i.'): '.$members_id[$i].'<br>';
    $i++;
}

echo '<br>';
echo 'Длина массива: '.count($members_id).'<br>';
echo 'Пользователь:'.$members_id[rand(0,count($members_id))];
```

Как можно организовать вывод массива в любом месте скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$members_id[$i] = $member->id;
```

Вы в цикле, на каждой итерации, создаете массив с одним единственным элементом.

Comment: Ох. действительно!
Переделал, теперь работает, спасибо огромное, аж стыдно за такую глупую ошибку.